# Alert Dialog flutter error only valid value 0:1

Tags: flutter

I did a simple alert function

Github : https://github.com/mohammad092/first

```
void newAlert(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context){
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('title text'),
        content: Text('content text'),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Text('dismiss'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

and i import it to my main.dart
also i imported the file which has the alert function

```
body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Alert'),
        onPressed: () {
          newAlert(context);
        }),
...
```

when i press the button on my device its keeps saying:

```
======== Exception caught by gesture library ================
The following RangeError was thrown while routing a pointer event:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
```

Comment: Your code is running without error on my device.

Comment: Try running `flutter clean` once.

Comment: which android version and phone ?

Comment: I ran on Redmi Note 9 and iOS simulator. Have you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: i runed flutter clean its not working

Comment: Check my answer. The issue is due to your `main.dart`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because your `main.dart` is not implemented correctly.You're declaring your `RaisedButton` directly in the `MyApp` class, instead you should make another Widget and pass that to `MyApp`, that will give the correct `context` to show the alert.

**Change your [main.dart](https://github.com/mohammad092/first/blob/main/main.dart) to this :**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:your_project/alert.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Alert'),
          onPressed: () {
            newAlert(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works ,,  so i have to return a class for home property , not a direct scaffold ,, for the code to work perfectly

Comment: You just have to make sure you're getting `context` of MaterialApp`. Which you'll get when you put `MaterialApp` in a separate class.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer as well. That'll help everyone in someway.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('AlertDialog Title'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
              Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Approve'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}

body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Alert'),
        onPressed: () {
          _showMyDialog()
        }),
...
```

Comment: its not working first throw undefined when i try to import it , i removed _ from the function and re import it it still saying 'context : ccontext' , i put context inside the function and its resaying it 'contextr: context'

Comment: because i am importing it idont want to use it inside MyApp Class

Comment: all files are availabe in github